# How to get an random row between a range of rows with LIMIT and OFFSET?

Tags: sql, sqlite, random, sql-order-by, sql-limit

How to get a random row from a selected 50 rows fetched using `LIMIT` and `OFFSET`? `OFFSET` value is dynamic, it can be `0`, `50`, `100`, and so on.

The current solution is to fetch all rows and then pick one random out of them via code, however, would it be more efficient to do it natively using SQL?

```
SELECT * 
FROM tableName
ORDER BY frequency DESC
LIMIT 50 OFFSET 0
```

Comment: Can't you use `random()` function  in order by ?

Comment: order matters in for these selected 50 rows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use your query as a subquery and pick a random row:

```
SELECT * 
FROM (
  SELECT * FROM tableName
  ORDER BY frequency DESC LIMIT 50 OFFSET 0  
)
ORDER BY RANDOM() LIMIT 1
```